# How to output a float number in hex in MIPS?

Tags: mips

the MIPS `syscall` only provides the way to output decimalism in hex form.

```
   print integer in hexadecimal 
   34   
   $a0 = integer to print   
   Displayed value is 8 hexadecimal digits, left-padding with zeroes if necessary.
```

by the way, the float number is stored in register in IEEE754 standard.

Comment: Are you running in the MARS environment?

Comment: @Pibben Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Use `mfc1` to copy the contents of the FPR to a GPR:

```
mfc1 $a0, $f0
li $v0,34
syscall
```